# Error while reviewing file after inserting data in redshift table

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have a table in **`Redshift`** in which I am inserting data from S3.
I viewed the table before inserting the data and it returned a blank table.

However, After inserting data in **`Redshift`** table, I am getting below **error while doing select * from table**. 
Command to copy data in table from S3 runs successfully without any error.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/amazon/jdbc/utils/DataTypeUtilities$NumericRepresentation error in
>   redshift

what could be the possible cause and sol for this?

Comment: How are you performing the query (what SQL client, connection type, etc)? It looks like a client error. Can you show us the table definition?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when the JDBC connection properties are set incorrectly.

If you are using postgres driver then ensure using postgres://

eg : jdbc:**postgresql://** HostName:5439/

Let me know if this works.